# Как работать с динамическим массивом, имея только указатель на него?

Tags: массивы, delphi, указатели

Как через указатель на динамический массив задать, например, его размер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

первая [ссылка](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/dynamic_arrays2.html) в [поисковике](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=delphi+%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2&lr=967)

и [ссылочка](http://lurkmore.to/RTFM) для заметки